# Logs generated by formatter.nvim

Tags: neovim, formatter, neovim-plugin

Where are the logs written to by [formatter.nvim](https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim)?

According to the [configuration sample](https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim#configure), I can enable the logs and even set the log level, but I could not figure out where the logs are written.

I tried ‘:LspLog’ but no formatter.nvim related logs were there.

I looked [around in code](https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim/blob/44c89f09dcc220dc2a9b056e93c3a87c86e79804/lua/formatter/log.lua#L13-L23) and found vim.notify however `:messages` is empty

```lua
function M.trace(txt)
  if
    config.values.logging
    and config.values.log_level <= vim.log.levels.TRACE
    and not M.is_current_format_silent()
  then
    -- NOTE: lsp thinks vim.notify takes one argument
    ---@diagnostic disable-next-line
    vim.notify(txt, vim.log.levels.TRACE, M.notify_opts)
  end
end
```